# Will a Raspberry Cameramodule v2.1 work with a Raspberry Pi Zero W board?

Tags: camera

I am brand new to Raspberry Pi and I today purchased my first board, a Raspberry Pi Zero W. This one: https://www.electrokit.com/en/raspberry-pi-zero-w-board.54741

I also purchased a camera to go with this, the Raspberry Pi Cameramodule v2.1. This one: https://www.kjell.com/se/sortiment/dator-natverk/enkortsdator/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-kameramodul-v2-p88053

Now when I try to connect the camera to my Pi Zero W the port of the Zero seems to be to small and It seems like it will not fit.

The camera that I bought says that it is "Compatible with all Raspberry Pi-models".

If i google images and see a working example it seems like their camera modules have a connector on the wire end that makes it go in. Do I miss a part that I need to connect to my camera?

While my camera wire looks like

Am I missing something or is the camera not working for a Zero board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't connect directly. You need an adapter cable as seen [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/zero-grows-camera-connector/). This adapts the fine pitch Pi Zero connector to the coarser pitch camera connector.

Comment: Ah ok so I need to replcae the current cable on the camera with a new cable?

Comment: This is what I am searching for i assume! https://www.electrokit.com/en/camera-adapter-150mm-for-raspberry-pi-zero.54743